# Random generated inputs for Selenium builder scripts

Tags: selenium, random

I'm trying to have an randomly generated inputs for one of my scripts on selenium builder as for example if I run the script for regeneration on multiple browsers at the same time for each release, eventually I will run out of values for future releases. Thus was looking for some random function which could help me to create a unique id every time I try to run the script.

Your help will be appreciated

Comment: What does your "id" look like? Have you tried Apache RandomStringUtils? https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

Comment: Hi, I just want to create users appended with a unique number whenever a script is run. I'm not too sure how to use this Apache RandomStringUtils in json script.

Comment: Your question is very generic, and it is difficult to give you a specific answer. Please have a read through [ask] before asking any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

The following will generate random strings that look like numbers. You can parse them with any [Java String methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) to generate whatever you need.

```
Math.random().toString()
org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(4)
```